# Why do some files appear twice in Unity Dash?

Tags: unity-dash, 16.10

Some files appear twice in the Unity Dash search although they only exist once on my file system. Does anyone know why this happens?

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Which sources do you have selected in the filter results?

Comment: @ElderGeek please see my update.

Comment: I did some testing (under 16.10). See my answer.

Comment: Please note that by changing the question entirely you have made it difficult for those who had your original question to find relevant answers. If the answer to a question results in a new question you should open that question separately. This allows up to help the maximum number of people as efficiently as possible. Thank you.

Comment: @ElderGeek thank you for your advise! I didn't know that and won't rename a question again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually have 2 copies of that document. You can confirm this by opening a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and issuing the command `find . -name "Timer?Time?Tracker.ods"` The reason I'm using `?` instead of spaces in the find command is in case you somehow ended up with [non-printing characters](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch25_07.htm) in the filename.

Comment: fyi, please see my answer for possibly an easier way

Comment: @orschiro: that would be an [entirely new](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) question.

Answer (score 4):

If you `right-click` on either of the icons in your first image, it'll tell you where the file(s) are located. You probably have the same file stored in two different places.

Comment: @orschiro to exclude the docs from Google Drive, open the dashboard filters and unhighlight the Google Drive button. (although the duplicate example that you illustrate doesn't look like a symlink, due to the file size).

Comment: Where can I find this Google Drive button in the dashboard filters? I cannot find it.

Comment: The list of filters in the expanded dashboard is scrollable. Either point to the filter area with your mouse and move your mouse's scroll wheel, or use the standard scrollbar on the right-hand-side of the list of filters.